# Why a sphere cannot have a Lorentzian Metric?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, semi-riemannian-geometry

I was listening to a Lecture and the lecturer said that a sphere cannot have a Lorentzian Metric. Is that accurate? If so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44861/for-which-b-it-is-possible-that-sn-can-have-a-lorentz-metric-why

Comment: Did he mean a two-dimensional sphere? If so, it's because the light cone could be used to define a non-vanishing vector field, contradicting the Hairy Ball Theorem.

Comment: I'm not sure what he meant, was just a one sentence statement. If the reason is what you're saying, then nothing is implied on $S^3$

Comment: S³ does have a Lorentzian metric, given the answers of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44861/for-which-b-it-is-possible-that-sn-can-have-a-lorentz-metric-why

Comment: It seems his statement was simply incorrect